# problesmas con mysqli_num_rows y consultas preparadas mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli, sql

Buenas tardes comunidad **stack**, estoy haciendo unas consultas preparadas con mysqli la consulta tiene exito pero si agrgo `mysqli_num_rows` me lanza error.

ejemplo este es el **codigo** que me lanza error...

```
$me=$_SESSION["id"];
 $name=$_SESSION["usuario"];
 $id =$_GET["id"];

$query3 = "SELECT user_id,post_id FROM post_views WHERE user_id = ?  AND post_id=?";
$result3=mysqli_prepare($conexion,$query3);
$ok3=mysqli_stmt_bind_param($result3, "ii",$me,$id);
$ok3=mysqli_stmt_execute($result3);
if ($ok3==false) {

    echo "error".mysqli_error($conexion);
}else{

   if (mysqli_num_rows($result3)>0) {// si el usuario ya esta no me lo insertes

         echo "not again";
   }else{ //si el usuario no estas insertalo

  $sql="INSERT INTO post_views (user_id,post_id,user_name)VALUES(?,?,?)";

   $result2=mysqli_prepare($conexion,$sql);
   $ok2=mysqli_stmt_bind_param($result2, "iis",$me, $id,$name);
   $ok2=mysqli_stmt_execute($result2);
}

 mysqli_stmt_close($result3);   

}
```

este es el error que me muestra la consola:

> "\r\n
> \n**Warning**: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to
>   be mysqli, object given in
>   **C:\xampp\htdocs\get_info_img_profile.php** on line
>   **35**
> \n
> \n**Warning**: mysqli_stmt_bind_param()
>   expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in
>   **C:\xampp\htdocs\get_info_img_profile.php** on line
>   **43**
> \n
> \n**Warning**: mysqli_stmt_execute() expects
>   parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in
>   **C:\xampp\htdocs\get_info_img_profile.php** on line
>   **44**\n{\"count\":\"10\",\"num_coments\":0,\"num_eva\":1,\"num_sync\":3}"

ahora bien si quito la condiccion de `mysqli_num_rows` procede y ejecuta el codigo ejemplo:

```
 $me=$_SESSION["id"];
 $name=$_SESSION["usuario"];
 $id =mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_GET["id"]);
 $count =$conexion, $_GET["count"];

$query3 = "SELECT user_id,post_id FROM post_views WHERE user_id = ?  AND post_id=?";
$result3=mysqli_prepare($conexion,$query3);
$ok3=mysqli_stmt_bind_param($result3, "ii",$me,$id);
$ok3=mysqli_stmt_execute($result3);
if ($ok3==false) {

    echo "error".mysqli_error($conexion);
}else{


$sql="INSERT INTO post_views (user_id,post_id,user_name)VALUES(?,?,?)";

   $result2=mysqli_prepare($conexion,$sql);
   $ok2=mysqli_stmt_bind_param($result2, "iis",$me, $id,$name);
   $ok2=mysqli_stmt_execute($result2);


 mysqli_stmt_close($result3);   

}
```

ojala me puedan ayudar con este error gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estuve haciendo pruebas sobre tu código y me encontré con algo muy extraño.

El [Manual de PHP dice que para hacer funcionar a `num_rows`](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) es necesario primero meter en el buffer el conjunto de resultado mediante `store_result`:

> El comportamiento de `mysqli_num_rows()` depende de si es que se
>   utilizan resultsets con o sin buffer. En caso de emplearlos sin buffer
>   `mysqli_num_rows()` no retornará el número de filas correcto hasta que
>   todas las filas del resultado hayan sido recuperadas.

Lo curioso es que con el estilo procedural no he podido hacerlo funcionar y no sé por qué (queda pediente de investigar). Sin embargo, si usamos el estilo orientado a objetos, por lo demás más claro y más moderno, todo funciona sobre ruedas.

**La cuestión es que antes de usar `num_rows` debes usar `store_result` para que el manejador conozca cuántas filas trajo la consulta.**

Otra opción (incluso más recomendada)  sería contar las filas con `COUNT` y leer el resultado de esa columna.

Propongo este código:

```
$me=$_SESSION["id"];
$name=$_SESSION["usuario"];
$id =$_GET["id"];

$sqlSelect = "SELECT user_id,post_id FROM post_views WHERE user_id = ?  AND post_id=?";
$stmtSelect=$conexion->prepare($sqlSelect);
$stmtSelect->bind_param("ii",$me,$id);
if(!$stmtSelect->execute()){
    echo "error: ".$conexion->error;
}else{
    /*Sin esto no puedes usar num_rows*/
    $stmtSelect->store_result();
    if ($stmtSelect->num_rows>0) {// si el usuario ya esta no me lo insertes
         echo "not again";
    }else{ //si el usuario no estas insertalo
       $sqlInsert="INSERT INTO post_views (user_id,post_id,user_name)VALUES(?,?,?)";
       $stmtInsert=$conexion->prepare($sqlInsert);
       $stmtInsert->bind_param("iis",$me, $id,$name);
       $stmtInsert->execute();
       $stmtInsert->close();
       /*Quizá convenga al menos decir que se insertaron registros*/       
    }
    $stmtSelect->close();      
}
$conexion->close();
```

Me he permitido dar nombres más descriptivos a las variables. Siempre es bueno saber lo que estás haciendo, nunca nombres variables en el estilo: `$variable1, $variable2, $variable999999` ... llegados a ese punto te quiero ver cuando quieras saber qué hace la variable `$variable999999` o cuando otro programador tenga que revisar tu código o el mismo sea incorporado a un trabajo en equipo.

Comment: genial @A. Cedano XD muy comico lo de las variables y numeros jaja si es algo que tengo que cambiar provare tu codigo luego te digo como me fue

Comment: funciono a la perfection creo que optare por la forma orientada a objeto gracias @A.Cedano!!

Answer (score 0):

La variable `$result3` es un objeto y no el resultado del query.  La forma correcta seria asi:

```
if($result3->num_rows > 0) {
```

Comment: disculpa lo puse mal, si ya lo habia intentado pero me lanza otro error es este `"\r\n<br />\n<b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in <b>C:\\xampp\\htdocsget_info_img_profile.php</b> on line <b>43</b><br />\n<br />\n<b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_stmt_execute() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in <b>C:\\xampp\\htdocs\get_info_img_profile.php</b> on line <b>44</b><br />\n{\"count\":\"10`

Comment: lo curioso es que si quito la condiccion de `if($result3->num_rows > 0) {` si funciona

Answer (score 0):

Segun veo la variable `result3` es solo preparada, por ende la que debe traer el query es `$ok3`

Deberia quedar asi:

```
if($ok3->num_rows > 0) {
```