# ¿Cómo comparo que una variable de mysqli_result sea igual a un número definido?

Tags: php, php7

Me encuentro practicando sobre como validar que un resultado de una consulta realizada sea igual a 1? si en la consulta realizada previamente ya le pase una condicional y en teoría se que solo va a haber un resultado.

esto es lo que tengo"

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM task WHERE id = $id";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

if ($mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
   echo "puede editar";
}
```

bueno la parte de la sentencia `if` se que se lo podía realizar en la version 5 de php, pero en la actualidad se debe cambiar y no estoy seguro si solo modificando unas sentencias y creando una condicional en la línea donde se encuentra la variable `$result` podría solucionarse.

esto sería según mis conocimientos actuales para la version 7 de php:

```
if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $query)) {
   $row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result); 
   if ($mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
      echo "puede editar";
   }
}
```

**Alguien me puede guiar para poder realizar la comparación?**

Comment: Esto no tiene nada que ver con la versión de PHP, ambos códigos son válidos tanto para PHP 5 como para PHP 7 (corrigiendo el error de la `$` al llamar a `mysqli_num_rows`). Ahora bien, si lo que quieres es verificar si hay registros, lo más seguro es lanzar un `SELECT COUNT(*) ...` Digo esto porque `mysqli_num_rows` depende de la configuración de buffer para funcionar y en algunos casos te dará `0` aunque haya datos. Revisa la nota en el Manual de PHP y [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/191529/29967) con más detalles sobre el tema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El código es correcto, tanto el primero como el segundo.
No obstante este último es un poco mejorable

```
if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $query)) {
   $row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result); 
   if ($row_cnt  == 1) {
      echo "puede editar";
   }
}
```

Ya que has guardado el número de filas variable $row_cnt pues la usas en el if