# solucion a Notice: Trying to get property 'num_rows' of non-object in

Tags: html5, css3, phpmyadmin, php7, localhost

Estoy empezando en la programacion y estoy subiendo mi primer proyecto a un hosting de prueba, el problema es que me arroja

> Notice: Trying to get property 'num_rows' of non-object in
> /storage/ssd4/734/20631734/public_html/biblioteca-san-gregorio-master/php/procesarlogin.php
> on line 7. en local si me funciona

```
<?php
   require_once 'conexionBD.php';
   $usuario=$_POST['USUARIO'];
   $contrase=$_POST['CONTRASEÑA'];
   $consulta="SELECT*FROM REGISTRO WHERE USUARIO='$usuario' AND CONTRASEÑA='$contrase'";
   $consultaBD=$mysqli->query($consulta);
    if($consultaBD->num_rows>=1){
   $row=$consultaBD->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
   session_start();
   $_SESSION['USUARIO']=$row['USUARIO'];
   $_SESSION['autenticar']=true;
   header("location:../inicio.html");

  }else{
  echo'<script type="text/javascript"> alert("DATOS ERRONEOS"); 
  window.location.href="../index.html"; </script>';
  }
  ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Si el mismo código funciona en local y no en remoto puede deberse a dos cosas:

1. La base de datos o el usuario/contraseña o el puerto o el nombre del host en que está la base de datos en remoto no son los mismas que en local y por tanto la conexión no se realiza con éxito.
2. La `Ñ` que tienes en `CONTRASEÑA` te puede estar rompiendo el código debido a problemas de codificación. En ese sentido, es recomendable evitar nombres de tablas, columnas y de variables PHP o elementos HTML que usen `ñ`, acentos o caracteres especiales.

Además de lo dicho, conviene que verifiques el estado de las cosas antes de intentar usarlas. Y, en realidad no necesitas usar `num_rows` en este contexto para saber si hay resultados, ya veremos por qué. Ademas, `num_rows` depende de la configuración del buffer<sup>1</sup> y puede darte una información errónea si no prestas atención a eso. Es así al menos en el caso de las consultas preparadas, a las cuales deberás pasar sí o sí, porque tu código es altamente vulnerable a ataques de *inyección SQL*.

Te propongo escribir el código de este modo (pondré comentarios para explicar cada cosa):

```
<?php
   require_once 'conexionBD.php';
   #Verificamos que la conexión es válida
   if ($mysqli) {
       $usuario=$_POST['USUARIO'] ?? NULL;
       $contrase=$_POST['CONTRASEÑA'] ?? NULL;
       #Verificamos que los datos no vienen en blanco
       if ($usuario && $contrase) {
           $consulta="SELECT * FROM REGISTRO WHERE USUARIO='$usuario' AND CONTRASEÑA='$contrase'";
           $consultaBD=$mysqli->query($consulta);
           #Verificamos que la consulta no tuvo fallo
           if ($consultaBD) {
               #Usamos el método específico
               $row=$consultaBD->fetch_assoc();
               #$row será false si no hay filas
               #verificando a $row evitamos usar num_rows
               if ($row) {
                   session_start();
                   $_SESSION['USUARIO']=$row['USUARIO'];
                   $_SESSION['autenticar']=true;
                   header("location:../inicio.html");
               } else {
                   $msg="No se encontraron registros";
               }
           } else {
               $msg="Error en la consulta";
           }
       } else {
           $msg="Datos incompletos para consultar";
       }
   } else {
       $msg="No hay conexión. Revise las credenciales";
   }
   #Imprimimos el mensaje ($msg) que hemos ido recogiendo
   printf('<script type="text/javascript">alert("%s"); window.location.href="../index.html";</script>',$msg);
?>
```

Si el código anterior te informa de que no hay conexión, debes verificar todos los parámetros que estás pasando para crear la conexión. Verificando que: la base de datos existe, el usuario / contraseña que estás usando son correctos. Verificar en qué puerto está corriendo mysql en ese servidor y si el nombre del host es distinto de `localhost` o de `127.0.0.1`. Revisa el [Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) para ver cómo pasar parámetros distintos en caso de que lo sean.

En cuanto a un posible problema con la `Ñ`, conviene que en `conexionBD.php`, si no lo has hecho, pongas un juego de caracteres adecuado a la conexión mediante:

```
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
```

Y conviene que en el `head` del HTML también pongas un juego de caracteres adecuado si no lo has hecho:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    ... Tus otros elementos del head aquí
</head>
```

Si sigues teniendo problemas con el juego de carácteres, puede que necesites hacer otras configuraciones, en PHP y en las tablas de base de datos. Para profundizar en este enfoque revisa **[esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/59510/29967)** a la pregunta: *[¿Por que el Carácter inspector (�) aparece en algunos datos obtenidos de la Base de Datos?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/59489/29967)*.

---

1. Para más detalles sobre `num_rows` y el problema del buffer, ver [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/191529/29967) y los enlaces en ella.

Comment: MUCHAS GRACIAS, POR SU AYUDA PUDE RESOLVER